# MVVM Combobox binding: Set and Get data from/to more sources

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, combobox

In my ViewModel class I have `Dictionary<int,string>` and `ObservableCollection<int>` properties.

```
private Dictionary<int, string> comboBoxDisplay;
public Dictionary<int, string> ComboBoxDisplay
{
  get { return comboBoxDisplay; }
  set
  {
    comboBoxDisplay = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged("ComboBoxDisplay");
  }
}

public ObservableCollection<int> Data{ get; set; }
```

In the constructor of ViewModel class, I add items to `Dictionary<int, string>` and make an instance of `ObservableCollection<int>` with "default" items.

```
ComboBoxDisplay = new Dictionary<int, string>();
ComboBoxDisplay.Add(1, "Never");
ComboBoxDisplay.Add(2, "Rarely");
ComboBoxDisplay.Add(3, "Sometimes");
ComboBoxDisplay.Add(4, "Often");
ComboBoxDisplay.Add(5, "Usually");
ComboBoxDisplay.Add(6, "Allways");


Data = new ObservableCollection<int>{1,1,1,1,1,1};
```

In XAML i have 6 `ComboBox` like:

```
<ComboBox Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxDisplay}" SelectedIndex="0" SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value">
```

They display data correctly but, I can't figure out how to bind data from `ComboBox` to `ObservableCollection<int>`. Each `ComboBox`should be bound to the specific item of `ObservableCollection<int>`. Something like `ComboBox1 {Binding Data[0].Value}, ComboBox2 {Binding Data[1].Value}`

Comment: Clarification, so the goal is to have a ComboBox that has the ComboBoxDisplay as its source and then when the user selects an item from the ComboBox it should get the correct Data?

Comment: @Mac It gets correct data, but i need to send that data in `Data[0]`, `Data[1]`.., I want to collect all selected value from `ComboBoxes` in `ObservableCollection`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try binding to SelectedValue?

```
SelectedValue="{Binding Data[0]}"
```

Comment: Well, I don't know how to do this, but I need to send data to some property I already received it in.

Comment: Yeah, that's it thank you very much. I forgot about `SelectedValue`, I tried many times with `SelectedItem`.